# How can I disable the on screen keyboard for pixelsense surface?

Tags: keyboard, pixelsense

I am writing a program for surface mode that has 4 movable boxes for users. There are textboxes to enter data. Since Windows only allows one keyboard at a time, I had to create four keyboards programmatically.

However, I can't find a way to disable the keyboard that pops up by default when I touch these textboxes.

I have read something similar was accomplished on a tablet by editing the registry key for a specific program.

How can I do this for PixelSense?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is possible to to set the textboxes to 
    Enabled="false"
and than catch the PreviewTouchDown-Event and display the Keyboard.